# How do I dereference in python? (Image Processing with openCV)

Tags: c++, python, image-processing, opencv, dereference

I've been looking all over the internet for a simple thinning algorithm and I stumbled across this: [Thinning algorithm](http://www.eml.ele.cst.nihon-u.ac.jp/~momma/wiki/wiki.cgi/OpenCV/%E7%B4%B0%E7%B7%9A%E5%8C%96.html) The problem is, I do not have too much experience with the dereference operator. Also, my project is in python which has a different way of handling this situation. So I have a few questions

1: What is this bit of code doing?

```
void myThinningInit (CvMat ** kpw, CvMat ** kpb)
  {
    / / Kernel for cvFilter2D
    / / The algorithm kpw kernel binary image and it has become a matching white, black,
    / / Convolution is divided into two sets of binary image was inverted kpb kernel, then take the AND
    for (int i = 0; i <8; i + +) {
      * (Kpw + i) = cvCreateMat (3, 3, CV_8UC1);
      * (Kpb + i) = cvCreateMat (3, 3, CV_8UC1);
      cvSet (* (kpw + i), cvRealScalar (0), NULL);
      cvSet (* (kpb + i), cvRealScalar (0), NULL);
    }.....
```

And 2: How can I translate this kernels creation into python?

He ends up making 8 kernels but I have no idea what their matrix form looks like.
I don't understand what "* (kpw + i)" or "* (kpb + i)" does in the grand scheme of the program.

3) Can I just make the kernels and store them in a list? If so, how could I do that?

UPDATE:

```
k = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
kpw = []
kpb = []

for i in k:
    kpw.append [i] = cv.CreateMat (3, 3, cv.CV_8UC1)
    kpb.append [i] = cv.CreateMat (3, 3, cv.CV_8UC1)
    cv.cvSet (kpw [i], cv.RealScalar (0), cv.NULL)
    cv.cvSet (kpb [i], cv.RealScalar (0), cv.NULL)
```

At first I didn't just had kpw [i] and it was throwing me an error. After a quick google search I found that you needed to index the array first and the way they did that was through append. I tried this bit of code in order to get 8 base kernels of 3x3 in size but I received this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/krtzer/Documents/python_scripts/thinning.py", line 14, in 
    kpw.append [i] = cv.CreateMat (3, 3, cv.CV_8UC1)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment

Does this mean I cannot have matrices in lists?

Comment: Is the `Kpw` (capital `K`) intentional (would be different to the `kpw` (lowercase `k`))?

Comment: [This C algorithm](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/thin_image.c) might be easier to follow. AFAIK OpenCV doesn't do anything like this and won't be of much help to you here (except maybe for the initial loading of the image).

Comment: @mathematical.coffee It's hard tell since I took that from the source code. It doesn't make sense for it to be capitalized since it's never declared or used anywhere else in the code.

And thank you guys for responding so quickly to this.

Answer (score 1):

That dereference is just creating a Matrix, without initialising its data.  The data is manually set to zero by those lines like `cvSet (* (kpw + i), cvRealScalar (0), NULL)`.

In python, you can just do the same thing in one hit with `numpy.zeros` and then use `cv.fromarray`.  Alternatively, use `x = cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv.CV_8UC1)` and then `cv.set(x, 0.)`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit - made a (pretty big) mistake in this answer, will explain

Looks like an array of `CvMat`s in both `kpw` and `kpb`.

Suppose I made a list of arrays `kpw = []` in Python.

The `*(kpw + i) = ...` is just like saying `kpw[i] = ...`.

Looks like the other code initialising the list of kernels to 3x3 matrices of 0, so you could do:

```
# make a list of 8  3x3 matrices of 0.
kpw = []
for i in xrange(8):
    kpw.append(np.zeros((3,3)))
    kpb.append(np.zeros((3,3)))
```

---

**Note**: I previously had:

```
kpw = [np.zeros((3,3))] * 8
kpb = [np.zeros((3,3))] * 8
```

which is **wrong** ! It produces 8 *references* to the *same matrix* within `kpw`, and so modifying `kpw[0]` will *also* modify all the other `kpw[i]`!

---

Then the `cvSet2D(*(kpb+0), 0, 0, cvRealScalar(0));` can be translated to :

```
kpb[0][0,0] = 0
```

Because `*(kpb+0)` grabs the matrix in `kpg[0]`, the `0,0` means element `0,0` of the matrix, and 0 is the value.

So: every time you see `*(kpb+i)` just substitute `kpb[i]` and you should be find translating that code.

Comment: 1. The loop in the example code makes 8 matrices not 7 and 2. You are using the same matrix 7 times, which will almost surely be a horrible bug!

Comment: Thanks for the catch in 1. As for 2., the code in the OP simply initialises 8 (thanks) matrices all of 0's. The python list `kpw` will contain 8 separate matrices, and modifying (say) `kpw[0]` will *not* also modify `kpw[1]`.

Comment: You might want to double check that.  Compare `id(kpw[0])` and `id(kpw[1])`.

Comment: D'oh, I didn't read the output properly when I tried this in the python interpreter. You're right. I'll leave the answer up as an example of what *not* to do.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new one in python. [Thinning(Python)](http://www.eml.ele.cst.nihon-u.ac.jp/~momma/wiki/wiki.cgi/OpenCV/Thinning%20%28Python%29.html)